# At grub rescue screen all filesystems shown by ls anser "unknown filesystem" what to do from there

Tags: grubrescue

Following an install of 22.04 with zfs:
Grub rescue screen comes up on first boot.
Grub rescue: ls shows:
(hd0)  (hd0,msdos5) (hd1)  (hd2)

When I run "ls" on each of them all I get on each one is
"Filesystem unknown"

I know for sure that the installer formatted at least 1 of the 4 partitions it makes as ext 4, or at least it told me the
`/'.. (root) partition was formatted as ext4.

I've read several of the many help sites concerning grub rescue.  All the ones I read depend on finding something recognizable in at least 1 of the partitions offered when one types "ls" at the grub recue prompt.  Since that has not happened with me. I'm wondering if boot has brought up a different disk from the one I installed on.

Can I make grub rescue tell which disk it has up?  Looking thru all the many commands that typing "help" shows, I'm not seeing anthing that looks particularly useful.

Once "ls" fails on every option shown what else can I do here.
And what is likely happening to land me on grub rescue?

Comment: Did you do a LVM with encryption? If not decrypted then partitions would be unknown. You have to mount & decrypt for report to show anything useful, if that applies. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  You show MBR(msdos) partitions. Most systems now are UEFI and should have gpt partitions?